# Lazy load video in javascript or jquery without any plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lazy-loading

I try to lazy load the video with jquery. I used the same lazy loading technique for images and background-images and it works perfectly fine but when i used same technique in video, it didn't work. What I did till now.

- change source src attribute to data-src attribute
- when the dom is ready, then change data-src attribute to src with the same values.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="video-section">
            <video muted loop autoplay preload="auto">
            <source data-src="hello.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
```

Javascript

```
let video_url=$("video source").attr("data-src");
$("video source").attr("src",video_url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works for you.

```js
var video_url=$("video source ").attr("data-src");

alert('Window loaded')

$(window).on('load', function(){
$("source").attr("src", video_url);
});
```

```css
.video-section{width:450px; height:300px; border: 1px solid red}
.video-section video{width:100%; height:100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-section">
            <video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">

  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
        </div>
```

Comment: Didn't get any error, but the video didn't play. Not even get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.load()` for video, like this:

```
<video_id>.load();
```